# S-Function 'librealsense_mex' does not exist - cannot generate new mex file

Tags: c++, matlab, simulink, mex, realsense

I have been trying to run the [Intel RealSense SDK](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/releases/tag/v2.50.0) on Simulink. The MATLAB wrapper obtained through the windows installation already has the mexw64 file along with the .cpp file and I tried to place an S-Function using it but receive the error `S-Function 'librealsense_mex' does not exist`. I have the [librealsense_cpp](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/c94410a420b74e5fb6a414bd12215c05ddd82b69/wrappers/matlab/librealsense_mex.cpp) along with librealsense_mex.mexw64 in the same correct path and when following this instruction https://stackoverflow.com/a/8997771/17727528, the Edit button can open and find the correct .cpp file but I still receive an error.

I tried to re-generate the mex file instead of using the one within the wrapper during installation but I recieve several error with mex function call failing.
My setup is:

```
>> mex -setup 

`C++ MEX configured to use 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)' for C++ language compilation.`
```

and I use the following function to generate the mex file

```
>> mex librealsense_mex.cpp
```

Attaching a some of the errors received below:

```
C:\Users\Silicon Synapse\OneDrive - Northeastern University\Desktop\librealsense-master\librealsense-master\wrappers\matlab\types.h:229:126: error: specialization of 'template<class T> typename std::enable_if<((! std::integral_constant<bool, ((std::is_arithmetic<_Tp>::value || std::is_pointer<_Tp>::value) || std::is_enum<_Tp>::value)>::value) && (! std::integral_constant<bool, MatlabParamParser::traits_trampoline::detector<T>::use_cells>::value)), mxArray_tag*>::type MatlabParamParser::wrap_array(const T*, size_t)' in different namespace [-fpermissive]
 template <> mxArray* MatlabParamParser::wrap_array<rs2::texture_coordinate>(const rs2::texture_coordinate* var, size_t length)
                                                                                                                              ^
In file included from C:\Users\Silicon Synapse\OneDrive - Northeastern University\Desktop\librealsense-master\librealsense-master\wrappers\matlab\librealsense_mex.cpp:1:0:
C:\Users\Silicon Synapse\OneDrive - Northeastern University\Desktop\librealsense-master\librealsense-master\wrappers\matlab\MatlabParamParser.h:311:1: error:   from definition of 'template<class T> typename std::enable_if<((! std::integral_constant<bool, ((std::is_arithmetic<_Tp>::value || std::is_pointer<_Tp>::value) || std::is_enum<_Tp>::value)>::value) && (! std::integral_constant<bool, MatlabParamParser::traits_trampoline::detector<T>::use_cells>::value)), mxArray_tag*>::type MatlabParamParser::wrap_array(const T*, size_t)' [-fpermissive]
 MatlabParamParser::wrap_array(const T* var, size_t length)
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:\Users\Silicon Synapse\OneDrive - Northeastern University\Desktop\librealsense-master\librealsense-master\wrappers\matlab\MatlabParamParser.h:340:0,
                 from C:\Users\Silicon Synapse\OneDrive - Northeastern University\Desktop\librealsense-master\librealsense-master\wrappers\matlab\librealsense_mex.cpp:1:
C:\Users\Silicon Synapse\OneDrive - Northeastern University\Desktop\librealsense-master\librealsense-master\wrappers\matlab\types.h: In function 'typename std::enable_if<((! std::integral_constant<bool, ((std::is_arithmetic<_Tp>::value || std::is_pointer<_Tp>::value) || std::is_enum<_Tp>::value)>::value) && (! std::integral_constant<bool, MatlabParamParser::traits_trampoline::detector<T>::use_cells>::value)), mxArray_tag*>::type MatlabParamParser::wrap_array(const T*, size_t) [with T = rs2::texture_coordinate; typename std::enable_if<((! std::integral_constant<bool, ((std::is_arithmetic<_Tp>::value || std::is_pointer<_Tp>::value) || std::is_enum<_Tp>::value)>::value) && (! std::integral_constant<bool, MatlabParamParser::traits_trampoline::detector<T>::use_cells>::value)), mxArray_tag*>::type = mxArray_tag*; size_t = long long unsigned int]':
C:\Users\Silicon Synapse\OneDrive - Northeastern University\Desktop\librealsense-master\librealsense-master\wrappers\matlab\types.h:234:23: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
     for (int x = 0; x < length; ++x)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.